# Map data from the DB table to the code

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a design question.
I have an existing system I'm working on.
I'm adding a new feature to it which is called subscription (for user's subscriptions).

I have a table which holds subscription Types (various types of subscriptions which gives the users certain permissions).

Each row in that table has its own ID and Name.

Right now in the code, I have an enum which corresponds to those IDs in the DB and according to it I know what subscription type I'm dealing with and make the decision accordingly.

```
enum SubscriptionTypes{
Silver = 1,
Gold = 2
....

}
```

My question is: Is there a better way to map those subscription types (or any other "types table" to the code?
Or since those values are not going to change in the DB it's ok.
I think it's more relevant if I have a few environments with there's own DBs and the IDs might change

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can save the data about the subscription in json or xml format and then deserialize it accordingly.this will give you the flexibility to add new subscription types in the future and not change the actual code.

Comment: Interesting. That's one approach but I have to tell you I didn't encounter this solution anywhere else. Normally the data is saved in some sort of a data store (even though a file is another one)

Comment: You dont really have to store the data about the subscription types in a file, maybe you can store it in a table in database and maybe give a UI window which lets admin users to edit the types. And internally you can store the data as JSON or XML.

Comment: I see. So the data in the DB would be saved but there'll be some kind of a converter which will map those values to the ones that I want in the file and work with those values in code? The whole idea about those IDs is that they are taken from a primary column table so the user can't change them.

Comment: If you are absolutely certain that the values for the subscription type will never change maybe its ok to keep as a enum . Or maybe as a json file inside your solution folder which you deserialize this still gives you the flexibility to add new things in the future if necessary.

Comment: Ok. thanks. Sounds like a good idea.
I would like to hear if there are other known solution to this issue.